# increment a variable foreach record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this query :

```
#create table #tmp_table( n_progressive int , name char(10), 
id_numeric(11,0) )


    declare @i int = 0  declare @c int declare n_progressive int = 0


    declare @var_table table ( name char(10), id_number numeric(11,0) )

    insert into @var_table( name, id_number ) select name,id_number from MainTable

    select @c= count (*) from @var_table

    while(@i<@c) begin set @n_progressive = @n_progressive + 1

    insert into #Tmptable( n_progressive  , name , id_numeric ) select @n_progressive ,name,id_numeric from @var_table

    end
```

The records in var_table are 4. and for each record I want the n_progressive to be incremented +1.

The result of the query above is this :

```
+--------------+----------+------------+
|n_progressive | name     | numeric_id |
+--------------+----------+------------+
|1             |   RM1    |   1        |
|1             |   RM2    |   2        |
|1             |   RM3    |   3        |
|1             |   RM4    |   4        | 
|2             |   RM1    |   1        |
|2             |   RM2    |   2        |
|2             |   RM3    |   3        |
|2             |   RM4    |   4        |
|3             |   RM1    |   1        |
|3             |   RM2    |   2        |
|3             |   RM3    |   3        |
|3             |   RM4    |   4        |     
|4             |   RM1    |   1        |
|4             |   RM2    |   2        |
|4             |   RM3    |   3        |
|4             |   RM4    |   4        |    
+--------------+----------+------------+
```

What I want is this :

```
+---------------+----------+-------------+
|n_progressive  | name     | numeric_id  |
+---------------+----------+-------------+
|1              |   RM1    |   1         |
|2              |   RM2    |   2         |
|3              |   RM3    |   3         |
|4              |   RM4    |   4         | 
+---------------+----------+-------------+
```

I don't want to use Cursors.

Comment: Tip: Best practice is to include a _question_ in your "question".

Answer (score 3):

You are selecting all the records from `@var_table` in each iteration of the loop, that's why you get all the records times 4 (the count of records in `@var_table`).

However, you don't need a loop at all, and you should strive to avoid loops any time you are using SQL anyway, since SQL works best with a set based approach and not a procedural approach (For more information, read [RBAR: ‘Row By Agonizing Row’](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar-row-by-agonizing-row/) and [What is RBAR? How can I avoid it?](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic642789-338-1.aspx))

Instead of a loop, you can simply use the `row_number()` window function to get the `n_progressive` value:

```
insert into #Tmptable( n_progressive, name, id_numeric) 
select row_number() over(order by name), name, id_numeric 
from @var_table
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not restricting the INSERT to read one row from your source table, you're copying the ***whole*** table multiple times.  To ***directly*** fix what you are ***trying*** to do, you should do something like this...

```
while(@i<@c) begin

    set @n_progressive = @n_progressive + 1

    insert into
      #Tmptable( n_progressive  , name , id_numeric )
    select
      @n_progressive, name, id_numeric
    from
      @var_table
    WHERE
      id_number = @i    -- Only one row

    SET @i = @i + 1     -- Move to the next row

end
```

A better idea could be to use `ROW_NUMBER()`, avoiding the need for the loop and much of the other boiler plate code.

```
insert into
  #Tmptable( n_progressive  , name , id_numeric )
select
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id_numeric),
  name,
  id_numeric
from
  @var_table
```

A better idea still could be to use an identity column, and let the table do the number allocations.

```
create table
  #tmp_table(
    n_progressive int       IDENTITY(1,1),
    name          char(10)               , 
    id_           numeric(11,0)
  )

insert into #Tmptable(name , id_numeric )
select name, id_numeric
from MainTable
ORDER BY id_numeric
```

Comment: It's worth noting, to the OP, that an `IDENTITY` column shouldn't be relied on to provide sequential numbers. If a row is deleted, or updated, you will have missing numbers, or numbers that might not be in the "correct" position any more.

Comment: @Larnu That will happen no matter what method is used.  All methods described involve creating a new temp table and populating it with sequentially ordered values.  ***None*** of them would re-order the values when an item is subsequently deleted, without recreating or repopulating the temp table.  One could, instead, create a view with the `ROW_NUMBER()` included, so dynamically allocating the id's every time the view is queried, but that has huge risks due to the volatility.  I would not suggest that without knowing first exactly how this would be used.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
with n as (
      select 1 as n
      union all
      select n + 1
      from n
      where n < @n_limit
     )
select n.n, name + cast(n.n as varchar(255)), n.n as numeric_id
from n
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

Comment: Wouldn't a simple row_number() work - the RMx part is coming from `select name,id_number from MainTable`

Comment: This would actually be a form of RBAR here; which is no better than a `WHILE`.

Comment: @Larnu My experience is that using T-SQL `WHILE` is still slower, because the "loop" created in this case is in C rather than in a high level interpreted language.  As the "loop" is achieved through recursion  there may come a point where the recursion's overheads make it's performance degenerate to being slower than a `WHILE` in T-SQL, but I'd expect that to require ***very*** deep recursion.  I still, however, agree that the loop simply isn't required at all.

Comment: @MatBailie Would you prefer it I had instead said *"which makes it not much better than a `WHILE`?"* 